# Unable to set session in server,working in localhost

Tags: php, session

I am setting user id to the session on login in my website.On echoing the session variable soon after being set, it is displayed.But after that iam redirecting this to another page where session is strated and then checked for the session.But it displays error message that undefined index user_id.This code is working in localhost,was working in server also.But now it displays error.Unable to login to the website due to the problem in setting session.

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
header('location:home.php');
```

In home.php

```
include('session.php');
```

in session.php

```
session_save_path('include/session_store');
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])))
{
header('location:signin.php');
}
```

On advise from fellow stackoverflow users ,I tried this.Created a test.php file.

```
session_save_path('include/session_store');
session_start();
$_SESSION['yahoo'] = 'yahoo';
header('location:test2.php');
```

in test2.php

```
session_save_path('include/session_store');
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['yahoo'];
```

Now in localhost yahoo is printed.But in server, blank screen is displayed.The session_store folder contain some 0kb files also.

Comment: In the file with the `header('location:home.php')`, do you have `session_start()`?

Comment: did u write `session_start` on `home.php` file?

Comment: tip: write `exit();` just after `header()`

Comment: I have added session_start in session.php.So is there any need to start session seperately in home.php?

Comment: ask your server people to set the session path on the server. if the same page is working on the localhost and not on the server, it is for sure that the server is not able to same the session.

Comment: But the login and session is working in other sites hosted in the same server.

Answer (score 0):

make sure yout do `session_save_path('include/session_store');
session_start();` on signin.php and also make sure `include/session_store` is writable

you said its working on,localhost, then definitely problem is include/session_store is not writable.

Comment: session_store is also writable.Is there any probability this can be some server configuration issue?But the code was working yesterday.I replaced the recently edited code with the previously working code.But in vein.

Comment: Also when I checked a 0 byte file is created every time I try to login.

Comment: please try some other simple dummy code based on session by hand if that works, it means issue is about your php files, else means server issue,

Comment: and check phpinfo carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have right permissions on **include/session_store** ? It has to be 777. 
You may print **echo session_save_path()** to ensure that the option is setted.
And at last, without changing the save_path the session works correctly? Your server may have some redirecting rules (mod_proxy) that could have repercussion on your session.

If you have php 5.4 you could try to print **session_status()**
http://www.php.net/manual/it/function.session-status.php

Comment: I added the code session_save_path('include/session_store'); because the session was not being set.

Comment: try to print out php_info. I think this issue depends on server setting either php or apache

Comment: I tried printing php_info,but not able to find anything.On enabling error reporting,the displayed error message is undefined index user_id.

Comment: there is a section related to session information into phpinfo, thats why. If php is correctly configured... remains only apache... Have you veryfied this issue from other computers too?

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be from the path where the session is stored
On your Web hosting file manager set the session path to /tmp/

If there's no folder called tmp then create it

Comment: Please share more details. The problem about permissions for the session storage folder was already mentioned in the other answers, which are more than eight years old. Do you want to highlight anything new?

Comment: Looks like this question was asked 8 years ago. Maybe focus your efforts on recent questions where the poster might still be seeking an answer.